# Dualwielding non-proficient Pact Weapon: are you proficient with the off-hand?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

Pact of the Blade states:

> You are proficient with [your pact weapon] while you wield it.

If your PW is a shortsword (or any other non-simple weapon), and you are wielding a regular shortsword in your off-hand, do you get to add your proficiency bonus to your off-hand attack?

My guess is no, that you're only proficient with the actual PW, and not any other weapon, even if it's exactly the same 'type.' But it's still a bit... odd.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are only Proficient with that pact weapon itself. While you are wielding it generally implies using it. Otherwise you could carry or hold an item/weapon and claim it's bonus's for your main hand because you're "wielding it".

If you were granted proficiency with the weapon type, it would state, 
You are proficient with the weapon type of your pact weapon while you wield it.

You could still use the pact weapon in the off-hand if it's type is light, and would maintain proficiency.

Comment: If it just said "You are proficient with your pact weapon." then it might imply that it gave you a free weapon proficiency.